# How to Map top element in Json to Java Class

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, pojo

I need to parse the input json string into Java Object. I am using jackson annotation for that.

Input Json:-

```
{
"employee":{
  "id":123,
  "name":abc,
    department:{
      "id":123,
      "name":"xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

Pojo File:-

```
public class Employee {

@JsonProperty("name")
protected String name;
@JsonProperty("department")
protected List<Department> departments;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public List<Department> getDepartment() {
    return departments;
}
public void setDepartment(List<Department> departments) {
    this.departments = departments;
}
}
```

I am getting the below exception while using `mapper.readValue(jsonString, Employee.class)` statement:

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "employee"

if i use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` nothing is getting mapped to my Employee object. Can anybody suggest what i am missing ?

Thanks,

Comment: What is Sport.class?

Comment: @JBNizet updated the code

Comment: OK, then read the duplicates.